# Panel regression gives error "exog does not have full column rank"

Tags: python, pandas, regression, jupyter, linearmodels

I am trying to estimate a panel regression (see: https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/panel/examples/examples.html)

My data is formatted like that (thats just an example snippet; in the orginal file there are 11 columns plus the timestamp and thousands of rows):

**What I have**

```
Timestamp   Country Dummy   Pre Post    All_Countries   Timestamp
1993-11-01  1               0   1       6.18    1993-11-01
1993-11-02  1               0   1       6.18    1993-11-02
1993-11-03  1               0   1       6.17    1993-11-03
1993-11-04  1               1   0       6.17    1993-11-04
1993-11-15  1               1   0       6.40    1993-11-15
1993-11-01  2               0   1       7.05    1993-11-01
1993-11-02  2               0   1       7.05    1993-11-02
1993-11-03  2               0   1       7.20    1993-11-03
1993-11-04  2               1   0       7.50    1993-11-04
1993-11-15  2               1   0       7.60    1993-11-15
1993-11-01  3               0   1       7.69    1993-11-01
1993-11-02  3               0   1       7.61    1993-11-02
1993-11-03  3               0   1       7.67    1993-11-03
1993-11-04  3               1   0       7.91    1993-11-04
1993-11-15  3               1   0       8.61    1993-11-15
```

**How you can re-create it**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp" : ['1993-11-01' ,'1993-11-02', '1993-11-03', '1993-11-04','1993-11-15'], "Pre" : [0 ,0, 0, 1, 1], "Post" : [1 ,1, 1, 0, 0],  "Austria" : [6.18 ,6.18, 6.17, 6.17, 6.40],"Belgium" : [7.05, 7.05, 7.2, 7.5, 7.6],"France" : [7.69, 7.61, 7.67, 7.91, 8.61]},index = [1, 2, 3,4,5])
df


 index_data = df.melt(['Timestamp','Pre','Post'], var_name='Country Dummy', value_name='All_Countries')

index_data['Country Dummy'] = index_data['Country Dummy'].factorize()[0] + 1
                     # pd.Categorical(out['Country Dummy']).codes + 1
timestamp = pd.Categorical(index_data['Timestamp'])
index_data = index_data.set_index(['Timestamp', 'Country Dummy'])
index_data['Timestamp'] = timestamp
index_data
```

**What I do **

```
!pip install linearmodels
from linearmodels.panel import PooledOLS
import statsmodels.api as sm
exog_vars = ['Pre','Post']
exog = sm.add_constant(index_data[exog_vars])
mod = PooledOLS(index_data.All_Countries, exog)
pooled_res = mod.fit()
print(pooled_res)
```

**What I get **

"ValueError: exog does not have full column rank."

**Question**

Anyone an idea what could cause that problem?

**Idea**

Is it because my data should be formatted like that (see example in link at the top):
--> and if yes, how could I get that

```
Timestamp   Country Dummy   Pre Post    All_Countries   Timestamp
1993-11-01  1               0   1       6.18    1993-11-01
1993-11-02                  0   1       6.18    1993-11-02
1993-11-03                  0   1       6.17    1993-11-03
1993-11-04                  1   0       6.17    1993-11-04
1993-11-15                  1   0       6.40    1993-11-15
1993-11-01  2               0   1       7.05    1993-11-01
1993-11-02                  0   1       7.05    1993-11-02
1993-11-03                  0   1       7.20    1993-11-03
1993-11-04                  1   0       7.50    1993-11-04
1993-11-15                  1   0       7.60    1993-11-15
1993-11-01  3               0   1       7.69    1993-11-01
1993-11-02                  0   1       7.61    1993-11-02
1993-11-03                  0   1       7.67    1993-11-03
1993-11-04                  1   0       7.91    1993-11-04
1993-11-15                  1   0       8.61    1993-11-15
```

Answer (score 3):

That error is being raised because `Pre` is a linear combination of `Post`. You should only use one of those columns because the other doesn't add information (and breaks the algebra behind your model). In this case:

```
Pre = 1 - Post
```

This is the same reason you drop one dummy that will serve as a baseline when running an OLS model.

This should work:

```
exog_vars = ['Post']
exog = sm.add_constant(index_data[exog_vars])
mod = PooledOLS(index_data.All_Countries, exog)
pooled_res = mod.fit()
```